# Parameter value coverage for C++

Tags: c++, c, unit-tests

I am strengthening my Jenkins build process and adding a few more checks.

I just stumbled across [Parameter value coverage](http://www.rhyous.com/2012/05/08/unit-testing-with-parameter-value-coverage-pvc/), which alas only handles C# code.

Is there anything similar for C / C++ ?

> Parameter Value Coverage (PVC) is the ability to track coverage of a
>   method based on the common possible values for the parameters accepted
>   by the method.
>
> Current code coverage tools fail to take into consideration the
>   possibility that a value for a parameter is not handled resulting in a
>   bug. However, there may not be any code addressing this value in any
>   way, introducing the possibility of obtaining 100% code coverage or
>   line coverage (LC) without detecting the bug.
>
> If the common values for types, especially primitive types and known
>   types, are documented and methods that use them are required to have a
>   test for each possible parameter value, bugs can be avoided.
>
> The following is a table of parameter value requirements for an int or
>   System.Int32 and string or System.String. A unit test should exist for
>   each of the possible values in order to have 100% PVC.
>
> **System.Int32**
>   A positive integer
>   A negative integer
>   Zero
>   int.MaxValue or 2,147,483,647
>   int.MinValue or -2,147,483,648
>
> **System.String**
>   A null string
>   An empty string, String.Empty, or “”
>   One or more spaces ” “
>   One or more tabs ” “
>   A new line or Environment.NewLine
>   A valid string.
>   An invalid or junk string
>   Unicode characters such as Chinese

Comment: You want to know, for each category of parameter value, whether a function has been tested with just that category? (e.g., for a two-parameter function, that each parameter has been exercised independently)?  Or that *all* combinations of parameter categories have been applied to a function?

Comment: Given the paucity of answers so far, I will take anything that I can get :-/

Comment: In the absence of alternatives: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf

Comment: A very interesting read. I already use gcov to ensure that I get 100% code coverage in unit test.. But that doesn't cover what I describe in the question. Maybe I will code my own - FOSS always looks good on the CV/resume ;-)